# System.Timers.Timer difference between Enabled = true and .Start()

Tags: c#

System.Timers.Timer difference between Enabled = true and .Start()? What is the difference?

Comment: Note that while the marked duplicate pertains to a different `Timer` class, the answer is exactly the same, and could have been found yourself just by either a) searching Stack Overflow or b) reading the documentation. This question shows no evidence of you having done any research, nor is it a useful addition to the Stack Overflow site.

Comment: Just look at the source code: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/timers/system/timers/Timer.cs,282

Answer (score 4):

Read the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.enabled(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Setting Enabled to true is the same as calling Start, while setting Enabled to false is the same as calling Stop.